# How do I get my Excel Ribbon to work?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I am new to Excel, as this is one of my first times using it, and I am having trouble clicking elements that are on the Excel Ribbon. I would like to create a "What-If Analysis" for the simple table below, but when I press the "What-If Analysis" Ribbon item, nothing shows up. There is no-pop up or anything.

I also have this issue of things not showing up for nearly every tab that has a drop-down arrow on the Ribbon. How do I fix this? I am using a Mac with 2016 version of Excel (version 15.20). Any help is appreciated.

[image: A screenshot of Excel with a simple table. The populated cells of the table are highlighted in gray and there is a thick selection box border surrounding them. In the Ribbon interface, a button titled "What-If Analysis" and a drop-down arrow next to it are also highlighted in gray.]

Comment: If I click on "What if analyses" I get a drop down with options for "Scenario Manager", "goal seek" and "data table". Clicking anyone of the boxes brings up pop-up windows with options for each tool. If you don't you might have a corrupt installation or bigger system problems. Can you edit any cells using the keyboard? What about ribbons in Word or Powerpoint?

Comment: Come to think of it, I've had similar issues on Windows PCs when the window focus was being occupied by another pop-up window (e.g. a security error, a pop-up message etc) which would prevent certain actions or pop-ups to take window focus. It sometimes helped to task switch (alt-tab on windows, cmd+tab on mac) to find the hidden pop-up. Another thought, isn't your document read-only by any chance? Does it do the same if your restart pc, restart Excel, and open a new blank spreadsheet?

Comment: @EdmondHelen Your question has had some minor edits made to it. Please review the changes and feel free to update the question further as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

Possible causes for this behaviour:

- You might have a corrupt installation of Office, or bigger OS
  problems -> reinstall Office or run updates.
- The window focus is being occupied by another pop-up window (e.g. a security error, a pop-up message etc) which could prevent certain ribbon actions or   pop-ups to retake window focus -> task switch to find the offending pop-up and close.
- You might have a faulty add-on installed -> run Excel/any office app in safe-mode by holding CTRL when launching the app. If this solves the issue, enter settings and disable all add-ons. Re-enabled one-by-one to find the offending add-on. Could very likely be Adobe Acrobat or similar PDF add-ons.
- Finally you can try disabling/enabling "Hardware Graphics Acceleration" under advanced options in each Office app.